# Illegal character error while compiling Java sources

Tags: java

I have compilation errors on my java files:

```
TestResponse.class:3: error: illegal character: \0
```

Is it something related to encoding?

Comment: we gonna need some code here!

Comment: Are you certain you're not trying to compile a `.class` file?

Comment: Seems like a line-break encoding error to me, as mentioned already, hard to tell without seeing more. And make sure you compile the .java file then run the .class, not the other way around.

Comment: I was using java 1.7 and got this problem. Switching to java 1.6 fixed the problem.

Comment: I experienced this error message due to file system corruption, right before my machine crashed! In my case I was compiling a .java file, but it was zeroed out after reverting my changes to the file.

Answer (score 3):

It looks like one of:

- You're trying to compile a .class file
- The compiler is reading a
  corrupt class file from the classpath.

Answer (score 0):

Even I faced the same problem.
The problem was with the file format.
Simply save the file in ANSI format instead of Unicode or UTF format.
It worked in my case!
You can simply open the your code in notepad and Save As in ANSI Encoding character format!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this is the same problem, but it could be.  I zipped some java source from Mac OS X where it was compiling just fine, and copied it to Linux where I was getting these errors:

db/src/._SomeClass.java:1: error: unmappable character for encoding UTF8
...
db/src/._SomeClass.java:1: error: illegal character: \0
...

This file didn't exist on OS X, but I think it was created when I untarred the archive because the original .java file had extended attributes.

Back on OS X, I could see this when I inspected the permissions for SomeClass.java:
-rw-r--r--@
The @ at the end of the permissions indicates extended attributes.

To see the attributes:
xattr -l SomeClass.java

To remove them:
xattr -c Someclass.java

On Linux, I could just delete the ._SomeClass.java file, but removing the extended attributes on Mac OS X prevented it from happening again.

Answer (score -1):

The problem is that you probably do not have the encoding on ANSI.

If you have the encoding on Unicode you will recive the error